# Apply filters to *ngFor for a nested Object

Tags: angular, nested, pipes-filters

I'm using [this](https://embed.plnkr.co/l1oTNT/)  pipes example inside my app, and it works fine for simple objects, but not for nested objects, for example lets take the example in the link and change the auther to an object instead of string, now the author will transform from this :

```
"author": "George R. R. Martin",
```

To this :

```
"author": {
     "name": "George R. R. Martin",
     "age": 25
}
```

I also changed the filter value to adapt the changes :

```
[(ngModel)]="filter.author.name"
```

However after these changes the searcher is not working any more for the author input.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the filter is defined as an instance of the Book class: `filter: Book = new Book();`, which means that when you try to do this `[(ngModel)]="filter.author.name"` you get an error because the `Book` class defines `author` as a string, not an object with a `name` property.

A possible solution is to create an `Author` class with the required properties (i.e. name and age) and the correspondent `authorFilter` of type `Author`. You can then modify the filter to look for the nested property `age` when the filter is of type `Author`.

[Working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ubrsn4)

Comment: That's exactly what I did ( already mentioned it in the question ) but still now working.

Comment: I mean something a bit different from what you already tried, let me put together a quick stackblitz example

Comment: it will be great,were you able to do it?

Comment: Ok I spent some time building a Plunker that achieves the filtering with numbers, strings or objects. I've modified my answer to include the link. There are obviously other ways, potentially more elegant or efficient, to achieve the same thing, but this is one.

Comment: How is that diefferent from the link that I provided ?

Comment: Sorry, somehow Plunker didn't save my changes. I've redone the thing in StackBlitz, the link should be good now.